# Why table cell height is not shown properly in Firefox and IE browser?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

My tables cells height shows differently in Firefox and IE browser it does not recognize **height**

Here is fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4KPzK/)

Here is css :

```
#gradient-style
{
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 95%;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;        
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-top: none;
    margin: 2%;
    margin-top: 50px;  

}
#gradient-style thead td
{
    background: gray;              
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}

#gradient-style td
{
    padding: 6px; 
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    color: black;
    background: #DCDCDC;        
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px; 
}

#gradient-style tbody td:hover 
{
    background: #C0C0C0;
}
.tbl-content{   
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the height here:

```
.tbl-content{   
    width: 100%;
    /*height:600px; */  
   overflow: auto;
 }
```

Comment: i want maximum height of tbody 600px if table has more rows. i tried .tbl-content{ max-height: 600px; overflow-y: scroll;width:100%;} but it not working.

Answer (score 0):

because your table-content has a height of 600px and that is on the scope of the body. 
Some browsers like Chrome may notice this is in error and ignore it, but IE doesn't correct those kinds of things.

```
.tbl-content{   
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px; /* change this as you see fit */
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: i am adding .table-content class dynamically <tbody class="<%= (cnt > 0) ? "tbl-content" : ""%>"> .ie if no records are there in table then i am not adding .tbl-content class to <tbody>